# FileNotFoundError long file path python - filepath longer than 255 characters

Tags: python-3.x, filepath

Normally I don't ask questions, because I find answers on this forum. This place is a goldmine.

I am trying to move some files from a legacy storage system(CIFS Share) to BOX using python SDK. It works fine as long as the file path is less than 255 characters.

I am using `os.walk` to pass the share name in unix format to list files in the directory

Here is the file name.

> //dalnsphnas1.mydomain.com/c$/fs/hdrive/home/abcvodopivec/ENV Resources/New Regulation Review/Regulation Reviews and Comment Letters/Stormwater General Permits/CT S.W. Gen Permit/PRMT0012_FLPR Comment Letter on Proposed Stormwater Regulations - 06-30-2009.pdf

I also tried to escape the file, but still get `FileNotFoundError`, even though file is there.

> //dalnsphnas1.mydomain.com/c$/fs/hdrive/home/abcvodopivec/ENV Resources/New Regulation Review/Regulation Reviews and Comment Letters/Stormwater General Permits/CT S.W. Gen Permit/PRMT0012_FLPR\ Comment\ Letter\ on\ Proposed\ Stormwater\ Regulations\ -\ 06-30-2009.pdf

So I tried to shorten the path using `win32api.GetShortPathName`, but it throws the same `FileNotFoundError`. This works fine on files with path length less than 255 characters.

Also tried to copy the file using `copyfile(src, dst)` to another destination folder to overcome this issue, and still get the same error.

```
import os, sys
import argparse
import win32api
import win32con
import win32security
from os import walk

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Migration Script',
)

parser.add_argument('-p', '--home_path',  required = True, help='Home Drive Path')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['home_path']:
    pass
else:
    print("Usage : script.py -p <path>")
    print("-p <directory path>/")
    sys.exit()

dst = (args['home_path'] + '/' + 'long_file_path_dir')

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(args['home_path']):
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = (dirname + '/' + filename)
        path_len = len(file_path)
        if(path_len > 255):
            #short_path = win32api.GetShortPathName(file_path)
            copyfile(file_path, dst, follow_symlinks=True)
```

Comment: Since you are getting the data from an API, have you tried getting the data using urllib?

Comment: have you tried with `/?//dalnsphnas1.mydomain.com/c$/fs/hdrive/home/abcvodopivec/ENV Resources/New Regulation Review/Regulation Reviews and Comment Letters/Stormwater General Permits/CT S.W. Gen Permit/PRMT0012_FLPR Comment Letter on Proposed Stormwater Regulations - 06-30-2009.pdf` ?

Comment: can you post the piece of code that doesn't work too?

Comment: The 255-character path limit is a Windows thing.  The usual workaround is to `cd` (`os.chdir` in Python) into some directory on the problematic path and then use a relative pathname shorter than 255 chars to refer to the desired file.  You'll probably want to remember your original directory (`os.getcwd`) so you can `cd` back to there after you've dealt with the hard-to-reach file or subtree.

Comment: Dinesh, I am listing the files from a UNC Path. Not sure how urllib will work in this situation. Jean, I did try adding "\\\?\\" to the path, but no luck. Otto, chdir seems only option left for me right now. But I wish there is a better way to do this. Becuase I have large number of shares to migrate, which will slows me down considerably. Jean, I will post the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, figured out the solution (thanks to stockoverflow forum)

- switched from unix format to UNC path
- Then appending each file generated through os.walk with r'\\?\UNC' like below. UNC path starts with two backward slashes, I have to remove one to make it to work

  file_path = (r'\\?\UNC' + file_path[1:])

Thanks again for everyone who responded.

Shynee